# Error Running Jupyter Lab/Notebook and Most Conda Commands Following Update

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, jupyter-lab

After attempting to update conda packages, I am no longer able to start either Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab.  Most conda commands also result in an error in terminal. While each command results in a slightly different error, every one terminates in the following statement:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

For instance, attempting to run jupyter lab results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/server.py", line 14, in <module>
    from notebook.base.handlers import (
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 35, in <module>
    from notebook.utils import is_hidden, url_path_join, url_is_absolute, url_escape
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .server import ServerApp
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/server.py", line 26, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.base.handlers import (                          # noqa
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 34, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.utils import is_hidden, url_path_join, url_is_absolute, url_escape
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Attempts to use homebrew to reinstall libffi (as suggested elsewhere) have also failed.

Any assistance in getting back up and running would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: _After attempting to update conda packages_ Update how, can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes. Ran "conda update - - all". The update ran fine with no errors. Immediately afterwards, I was unable to start either jupyter lab or jupyter notebook.

Comment: Had you activated the environment, though?

Comment: Yes. Activated it successfully. And conda list executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem as well and needed to downgrade libffi to version 3.2.1.

I never explicitly installed libffi; it came along with the original environment creation.

Try this

```
% conda install libffi=3.2.1
```

I was able to install many packages but had failures with 
nb_conda_kernels and various jupyter lab extension installations.

Comment: Bingo. That did it.

Comment: dude you just like saved my life, many many thanks!!