# Conda commands (ie: conda env list, sypder, jupyter lab) no longer work after 'conda update conda'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I used 'conda update conda' and I'm now having some problems. I'm on osx. I can no longer open the Anaconda-Navigator App from finder, nor start spyder or jupyter lab from the terminal.  Below is the output I get if I try to open jupyter lab from the terminal.

I also added the contents of the base environment as requested.

I tried the command mentioned in this post but had no luck.
[Error Running Jupyter Lab/Notebook and Most Conda Commands Following Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61388066/error-running-jupyter-lab-notebook-and-most-conda-commands-following-update)

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    (base) Dylans-Mac-mini:~ dylanquinn$ jupyter lab
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/server.py", line 14, in <module>
        from notebook.base.handlers import (
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 35, in <module>
        from notebook.utils import is_hidden, url_path_join, url_is_absolute, url_escape
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
      Reason: image not found

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 6, in <module>
        from jupyterlab.labapp import main
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 14, in <module>
        from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .app import LabServerApp
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/app.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .server import ServerApp
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/server.py", line 26, in <module>
        from jupyter_server.base.handlers import (                          # noqa
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 43, in <module>
        from jupyter_server.utils import is_hidden, url_path_join, url_is_absolute, url_escape
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
      Reason: image not found
    (base) Dylans-Mac-mini:~ dylanquinn$
```

```
# packages in environment at /Users/dylanquinn/opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0  
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
applaunchservices         0.2.1                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
apptools                  4.4.0                    py37_1  
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0  
asgiref                   3.2.7                      py_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.4.1                    py37_0  
astropy                   4.0.1.post1      py37h01d97ff_1  
async_generator           1.10             py37h28b3542_0  
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.9.0                    py37_0  
bitarray                  1.2.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.4                      py_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     2.0.2                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37h776bbcc_0  
bs4                       0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
certifi                   2020.4.5.1               py37_0  
cffi                      1.14.0           py37hc512035_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cloudpickle               1.4.1                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.9                   py37_3  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
configobj                 5.0.6                    py37_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.9.2            py37ha12b0ac_0  
curl                      7.69.1               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.17          py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.17.2                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.17.2                     py_0  
dbus                      1.13.14              h517e14e_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0  
distributed               2.17.0                   py37_0  
django                    3.0.3                      py_0  
docutils                  0.16                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
envisage                  4.8.0                      py_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flake8                    3.8.2                      py_0  
flask                     1.1.2                      py_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
fsspec                    0.7.4                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             hb0f4f8b_2  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
glib                      2.63.1               h70d4741_1  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h3134771_0  
hdf4                      4.2.13               h39711bb_2  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
hypothesis                5.11.0                     py_0  
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3  
idna                      2.9                        py_1  
imageio                   2.8.0                      py_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib-metadata        1.6.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        1.6.0                         0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0  
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.13.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.15.2                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
joblib                    0.15.1                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json5                     0.9.4                      py_0  
jsoncpp                   1.8.4                h04f5b5a_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            6.1.3                      py_0  
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_0  
jupyter_server            0.1.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                2.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.1.4                      py_0  
keyring                   21.1.1                   py37_2  
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py37h04f5b5a_0  
krb5                      1.17.1               hddcf347_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.69.1               h051b688_0  
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.3                  h0a44026_1  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.16                 h1de35cc_0  
liblief                   0.10.1               h0a44026_0  
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                hd5207e6_2  
libogg                    1.3.2                h1de35cc_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h0a44026_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha12b0ac_1  
libtheora                 1.1.1                hb4e5f40_1  
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0  
libvorbis                 1.3.6                h1de35cc_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
llvm-openmp               10.0.0               h28b9765_0  
llvmlite                  0.32.1           py37h8c7ce04_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.5.0            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h1de35cc_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py37_0  
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37h9aa3819_0  
mayavi                    4.7.1            py37hd5f3a30_2    anaconda
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py37h959d312_0  
mock                      4.0.2                      py_0  
more-itertools            8.3.0                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
multitasking              0.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0  
nbformat                  5.0.6                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.49.1           py37h86efe34_0  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py37hce01a72_0  
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h7241aed_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37h3304bdc_1  
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
opencv-python             4.2.0.34                 pypi_0    pypi
openpyxl                  3.0.3                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h1de35cc_0  
packaging                 20.3                       py_0  
pandas                    1.0.3            py37h6c726b0_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    7.1.2            py37h4655f20_0  
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_3  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.4                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.4                         0  
psutil                    5.7.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.1                      py_0  
py-lief                   0.10.1           py37haf313ee_0  
pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py37ha12b0ac_0  
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0  
pyface                    6.1.2                    py37_0  
pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0  
pylint                    2.5.2                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h5bccee9_0  
pytest                    5.4.2                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.8.0                      py_0  
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.2                      py_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.5.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.4                h359304d_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0  
python-language-server    0.31.9                   py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.9                        py_0  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37h0a44026_0  
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.7.0                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.7.4                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.23.0                   py37_0  
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
rope                      0.17.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.9.4                    py37_1  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h6c726b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9fa6033_0  
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                46.4.0                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
simplejson                3.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_0  
sphinx                    3.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.1                      py_0  
spyder                    4.1.1                    py37_1  
spyder-kernels            1.9.1                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.17           py37haf1e3a3_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               h5c1f38d_1  
sqlparse                  0.3.1                      py_0  
statsmodels               0.11.1           py37haf1e3a3_0  
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0  
tbb                       2020.0               h04f5b5a_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toml                      0.10.0           py37h28b3542_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h1de35cc_1  
tqdm                      4.46.0                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
traits                    5.2.0            py37h1de35cc_0    anaconda
traitsui                  6.1.3                      py_0  
typed-ast                 1.4.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
typing_extensions         3.7.4.1                  py37_0  
ujson                     1.35             py37h1de35cc_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0  
voila                     0.1.21                     py_0    conda-forge
vtk                       8.2.0           py37h9bafd54_200  
watchdog                  0.10.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.9                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py37_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.8                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.19.4                   py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0  
yahoo-finance             1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0  
yfinance                  0.1.54                   pypi_0    pypi
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the base environment?

Comment: Can you add the output of `conda list libffi`? If you're lucky conda still works and `conda install libffi<3.3` should work as a workaround for now. Otherwise there will be some manual work required :-/

Comment: @AMC - thanks for the help. I added the contents of the base environment.

Comment: @cel - thanks for the help. conda install libffi<3.3 resulted in: -bash: 3.3: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, I forgot quotes - the command should have been: `conda install "libffi<3.3"`

Comment: @cel no luck with: conda install "libffi<3.3" I tried to post the output above but ran out of room. I'm happy to reinstall anaconda if that is a fix.

Comment: i decided to see if reinstalling anaconda fixed the issue

Comment: @Landy _i decided to see if reinstalling anaconda fixed the issue_ That's probably the best course of action. There seems to be a bunch of extra stuff in your base environment, so it's not surprising that something broke. Don't use the base environment for development!

Answer (score 0):

Updating conda can be tricky, depending on how it was installed previously.

To fix your current environment:
You can find and revert back to the previously working version using this command:

```
conda list --revisions
```

This will return a list of revisions to your conda environment, just
then select the revision you want (most recent working version) and run this command:

```
conda install --revision [n]
```